# PowerShell - to check multiple Port Status

Tags: powershell

I was trying to check whether the port is opened or not using powershell like follows.

My question is :  I want to check multiple ports such as 389,53,135. how can we do that?

Here is my script :

```
$Ipaddress= "xx.xx.xx.xx"
$Port= "389"

$t = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
$t.Connect($Ipaddress,$Port)
    if($t.Connected)
    {
        "Port $Port is operational"
    }
    else
    {
        "Port $Port is closed, You may need to contact your IT team to open it. "
    }
```

My desired output :

```
Port 389 is operational;Port 53 is operational;Port 135 is operational
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShells `Test-NetConnection` and just put that inside a loop that iterates over an array of ports.

For syntax and usage see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=windowsserver2022-ps